# How to have propositions and theorems have the same counter for the \declaretheorem command

Tags: environments, theorems, thmtools

I am using the `thmtools` and `thm-restate` packages so that I can restate theorems and propositions.
I use the `\declaretheorem` command as follows:

```
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Proposition, numberwithin=section]{proposition}
```

However, in the document I do not have propositions and theorems having the same counter. For instance, as the code currently is, I will end up with output like this:

```
Proposition 1.1

Proposition 1.2

Theorem 1.1
```

However, I want it to be like:

```
Proposition 1.1

Proposition 1.2

Theorem 1.3.
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `thmtools` documentation (*§ 3.2 Known keys to `\declaretheorem`*) we find

> **sibling** Value: a counter name. The theorem will use this counter for numbering. Usually, this is the name
> of another theorem environment.
> **numberlike** (Same as sibling.)
> **sharenumber** (Same as sibling.)

You can thus use the `sibling` key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[name=Proposition,sibling=theorem]{proposition}

\begin{document}

\section{Text}
\begin{proposition}
Foo.
\end{proposition}
\begin{proposition}
Bar.
\end{proposition}
\begin{theorem}
Baz.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]